# How do I recompile a ruby with RVM?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I installed Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM, and it works fine. I then made some changes in a ruby C source file, and I want to recompile and re-install it so I can use the changes. I haven't found any kind of *rvm recompile* command however.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Ah hah. `rvm uninstall [RUBY]` followed by `rvm install [RUBY]` does the trick.

or nicer:

```
rvm reinstall [RUBY]
```

Answer (score 60):

The problem with using `rvm [reinstall|install]` is that it will fetch and use precompiled binaries if it can find any. Sometimes, you *really* want to rebuild from source, probably because you're trying to use a more recent version of GCC (e.g. 4.8 or 4.9).

The correct flag is `--disable-binary`, not `--force`:

```
rvm reinstall --disable-binary 2.1
```

Comment: This helped when I upgraded from Fedora 23 -> 24 and the mysql2 gem no longer worked because it was compiled against an earlier libmysql.

Answer (score 12):

or `rvm reinstall [RUBY]`

---

Comment: I don't think so. The docs say: "It is equivalent to:

  rvm remove  [ruby-string]
  rvm install [ruby-string]
"

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
rvm install --force
```

It explicitly asks RVM to use existing sources, in earlier versions this was default - but might be very confusing.

So other commands in ther for installing:

```
rvm try_install <ruby>
```

Will only install if not yet installed (your problem)

```
rvm reinstall <ruby>
```

is the same as:

```
rvm remove [--gems] <ruby>
rvm install <ruby>
```

obviously some time saved with `reinstall`
and use [--gems] to also remove all the gems that were installed with ruby.

```
mkdir -p projects/smth && cd projects smth
rvm use 1.9.3@gem --install --create --ruby-version
```

will go to project, install 1.9.3 (if not yet installed), create the gemset, and create `.ruby-version` file (available only in RVM head before v. 1.11.0)
the other flgs:

- `--rvmrc` - already available in RVM - will create `.rvmrc` file
- `--versions-conf` - available only in RVM head before v. 1.11.0 - will create `.versions.conf` - a configuration file for your project, you can put there any important information about your project ... like node.js version