# Rails - Library not loaded: @@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, mysql2

I am fighting with an error that occurs when I run **rails s**:

```
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require': dlopen(/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.0.0-static/mysql2-0.3.16/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: @@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Reason: image not found - /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.0.0-static/mysql2-0.3.16/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

MySQL installed through **brew**.

Unfortunately I am not sure how to fix this issue, so I appreciate every help.

Thank you

Comment: Looks like a common problem, maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546698/library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-serv

Comment: I found this topic and made some modifications based on that, but still this. Is needed to restart system after that?

Comment: Shouldn't have to, no.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue on my rbenv setup after updating a few things in Homebrew. I simply recompiled Ruby and the problem went away. In this case it looks like you might want to recompile all the gems as well. According to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663005/how-do-i-recompile-a-ruby-with-rvm) you can run `rvm reinstall 2.0.0-p481` (recompiles ruby and removes all gems) and then re-bundle your project and you should be good to go.

I'm pretty sure what happened is a new version of openssl was installed as a dependency for something else I installed using Homebrew and that broke the linking between the compiled Ruby and the old version of libssl.